# Printing current coordinates to a label (Swift, Xcode8)

Tags: swift, xcode8

I'm a beginner, I'm studying Swift just for fun. Right now I'm studying the use of maps in apps and I'd like to print the current coordinates (latitude, longitude) to a label.

Now, I've managed to show the map and the current position on the map and get the coordinates of it but I need help how I could print these coordinates to the label.

This is what I've done so far:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var posizione: UILabel!
    //Map
    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!



    @IBAction func rileva(_ sender: Any)
    {

    }


    let manager = CLLocationManager()

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
    {
        let location = locations[0]

        let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01)
        let myLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
        let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span)
        map.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        print(location.coordinate)
        print(location.altitude)

        self.map.showsUserLocation = true

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `didUpdateLocation` function:

```
self.posizione.text = "latitude: " + String(location.coordinate.latitude) + ", longitude: " + String(location.coordinate.longitude)
```

Answer (score 0):

hi try this code :

```
posizione.text = "latitude : \(location.coordinate.latitude) - longitude : \(location.coordinate.longitude)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use.

```
self.posizione.text = "Latitude is \(location.coordinate.latitute) and longitude is \(location.coordinate.longitude)".
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.